# How to make directory and touch files in it in a one Linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

For example,I run  cd../mkdir AAA enter and cd AAA enter and touch file.a file.b.
Can I operate above steps just in one line?
Thanks for taking the time and sorry about that I am newbie to it.
I tried cd../mkdir AAA && touch file.a and it created file in the working directory.

Comment: please update the question to show your actual commands; `cd../mkdir AAA` is an invalid command ... I can't tell if this was a typo or pseudo code

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800845/create-file-and-its-parent-directory) might provide some alternatives.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create directory and files in it:

```
cd ../ && mkdir dirA && touch dirA/foo.txt && touch dirA/bar.txt
```

Verify:

```
$ ls dirA

bar.txt foo.txt
```

Comment: I wanna cd ../ and mkdir and touch in a single line and it say too many arguments

Comment: `mkdir dirA` will error (and fail) if `dirA` already exists; would be a bit safer with `mkdir -p dirA` which will ignore the 'already exists' error yet still succeed

Comment: @Islinntrue there's no problem with prepending `cd ../ &&` if I understood you correctly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Islinntrue, "too many arguments" either means that you passed more than one argument to `cd`, or that you passed so many arguments to `touch` that the arguments + environment variable space went over your operating system's limit (on Linux, typically 128kB). We'd need to see _exactly_ how you caused the problem to be able to speak to it with more specificity; there's nothing that's generally/broadly wrong with the stated practice.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- a new directory is to be created (but we'll also assume said directory may already exist)
- one or more (empty) files are to be created/touched

If the objective is to do the least amount of typing I'd recommend creating a custom function.

One (verbose) example:

```
mktouch() {
    local newdir="$1"                     # first arg is the new directory
    shift                                 # discard first arg

    mkdir -p -- "$newdir"                 # if $newdir already exists the "-p" says to ignore the 'directory already exists' error

    for newfile in "$@"                   # loop through rest of args and ...
    do
        touch -- "$newdir/$newfile"       # create file
    done
}
```

**NOTE:** OP could add this function definition to their login script (eg, `.profile` or `.bashrc`)

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ find dirA -type f
find: ‘dirA’: No such file or directory

$ mktouch dirA file.a file.b
$ find dirA -type f
dirA/file.a
dirA/file.b

$ mktouch dirA file.XYZ
$ find dirA -type f
dirA/file.a
dirA/file.b
dirA/file.XYZ
```

Comment: Put a `|| return` after your `mkdir` -- don't want to keep going if it fails.

Comment: (might also do something like `local newdir rc=0` at the top of the function, `|| rc=1` after the `touch` operations, and `return "$rc"` at the end)

Comment: ...I'd also think of adding some `--`s in there so if your `$1` starts with a dash it's still interpreted as a directory name rather than a flag. (`mkdir -p -- "$newdir"`, `touch -- "$newdir/$newfile"`, etc)

Comment: added the `--` and `local`; will let OP decide if they want to add the other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be the GNU `install` command with the `-m` and `-D` options:

```
for i in dirA/{foo.txt,bar.txt} ; do install -m 644 -D /dev/null "$i" ; done
```

directory created:

```
ls 
dirA
```

directory contents:

```
ls dirA/
bar.txt  foo.txt
```